# Two identical lambda expressions and one cannot be translated to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am querying EntityFrameworkCore.Jet access database with two identical expressions created in two different ways. One of them successfully queries the database and the other fails to translate.

Here is the code:

```
 public async Task<dynamic> Search([FromBody] SearchConditions searchConditions)
    {
        var exprs = new List<Expression<Func<AlleSerier, bool>>>();
        if (searchConditions.Field == SearchField.All || searchConditions.Field == SearchField.Author)
        {
            exprs.Add((a=>  EF.Functions.Like(a.Author, searchConditions.Text)));
        }
        if (searchConditions.Field == SearchField.All || searchConditions.Field == SearchField.Client)
        {
            exprs.Add(a => EF.Functions.Like(a.Client, searchConditions.Text));
        }
        if (searchConditions.Field == SearchField.All || searchConditions.Field == SearchField.ProjectManager)
        {
            exprs.Add(a => EF.Functions.Like(a.ProjMgr, searchConditions.Text));
        }
        if (searchConditions.Field == SearchField.All || searchConditions.Field == SearchField.ReportNumber)
        {
            exprs.Add(a => EF.Functions.Like(a.Number.ToString(), searchConditions.Text));
        }

        var query = exprs.Aggregate((e1, e2) => 
            e1 == default 
                ? e2 
                : Expression.Lambda<Func<AlleSerier, bool>>(Expression.OrElse(e1.Body, e2.Body).Reduce().ReduceExtensions(), e1.Parameters) 
                );



        Expression<Func<AlleSerier, bool>> expr = a =>
            EF.Functions.Like(a.Author, searchConditions.Text) ||
            EF.Functions.Like(a.Client, searchConditions.Text) ||
            EF.Functions.Like(a.ProjMgr, searchConditions.Text) ||
            EF.Functions.Like(a.Number.ToString(), searchConditions.Text);
        
        Console.WriteLine(query.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(expr.ToString());

        
        var res2 = await _repo.Reports.Where(query).ToListAsync();
        
        var res1 = await _repo.Reports.Where(expr).ToListAsync();


        return res2;
    }
```

As result, from the console I can read:

```
a => (((EF.Functions.Like(a.Author, value(LibraryReporter.Controllers.SubmissionController+<>c__DisplayClass3_0).searchConditions.Text) OrElse EF.Functions.Like(a.Client, value(LibraryReporter.Controllers.SubmissionController+<>c__DisplayClass3_0).searchConditions.Text)) OrElse EF.Functions.Like(a.ProjMgr, value(LibraryReporter.Controllers.SubmissionController+<>c__DisplayClass3_0).searchConditions.Text)) OrElse EF.Functions.Like(a.Number.ToString(), value(LibraryReporter.Controllers.SubmissionController+<>c__DisplayClass3_0).searchConditions.Text))

a => (((EF.Functions.Like(a.Author, value(LibraryReporter.Controllers.SubmissionController+<>c__DisplayClass3_0).searchConditions.Text) OrElse EF.Functions.Like(a.Client, value(LibraryReporter.Controllers.SubmissionController+<>c__DisplayClass3_0).searchConditions.Text)) OrElse EF.Functions.Like(a.ProjMgr, value(LibraryReporter.Controllers.SubmissionController+<>c__DisplayClass3_0).searchConditions.Text)) OrElse EF.Functions.Like(a.Number.ToString(), value(LibraryReporter.Controllers.SubmissionController+<>c__DisplayClass3_0).searchConditions.Text))
```

(which should mean that they are the same)

followed by:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<AlleSerier>
          .Where(a => __Functions_0
              .Like(
                  _: a.Author,
                  matchExpression: __searchConditions_Text_1) || __Functions_0
              .Like(
                  _: a.Client,
                  matchExpression: __searchConditions_Text_1) || __Functions_0
              .Like(
                  _: a.ProjMgr,
                  matchExpression: __searchConditions_Text_1) || __Functions_0
              .Like(
                  _: a.Number.ToString(),
                  matchExpression: __searchConditions_Text_1))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

If I comment out the `var res2 = await _repo.Reports.Where(query).ToListAsync();` the other query executes. Why?

Comment: "which should mean that they are the same" - really no; ToString is a very blunt tool; the first thing I'd try here is calling `query.Compile()` - does *that* work? (`Compile()` does a reasonable job of reporting problems, you see)

Comment: Also, look for .InnerException; FWIW my hunch here is that a ParameterExpression needs to be rewritten when merging the lambdas; easily done via an ExpressionVisitor subclass

Comment: @MarcGravell yes it does. What's more, if I swap the order of res1 res2 lines, then both execute without any problem.

Comment: Please don't play with orders of execution, the manually built expression is just wrong, do what Marc is saying, or just take a well known good implementation of predicate builder (because that's what you are trying to implement, and this "wheel" has been invented a long time ago). For EF Core both `Expression.Invoke` and parameter replacing work, but the later is more natural and works in every normal query translator.